# CSS value of a image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, jasmine

I have a image on the website. 
i should get the CSS value of Max_width for that image using java script for my Jasmine framework.

Can you please guid me.

Here is the code:

```
it("Should return Max-width value: '"+width+"'",function(){
      var width, item;
        item = OpenSpace.getElementById("OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_49_svgRoot");
        width = item.max_width;
        expect(result).toBe(width);



      alert(width);
```

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you want to get the current width of the image?

Comment: Please add the codesnippet to the question itself...

Comment: Yes. Added code to question. 
Yes. I wanted to get the max width of a image using JS.

Comment: You should show the code you want to test. Its hard to guess what you wanna accomplish. Also where was the `result` variable set. Why you have a variable in your spec description?

Answer (score 0):

clientWidth is the inner width of an element in pixels. It includes padding but not the vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered), border or margin.

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
```

Another solution:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
   alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

Hope it works

Comment: I am getting this error message: TypeError: document.getElementByid is not a function

Comment: the first answer is document and the last is image path

Comment: Try this last one, var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var curr_width = mydiv.style.width;

Comment: everytime, i am getting this error message: document.getElementByid is not a function

Comment: Can you please update your answer above so that we can trace the error?

Comment: I got the solutions for this here it is
{if (osMap){
  // destroy map object
  osMap.destroy();// kill this instance
  //hide empty div
  myMap = document.getElementById('map');
  if (myMap) {//myMap.style.display="none";}
   var width = myMap.style.display;
   alert(width);}